# External Hard Drive Going to Sleep CONSTANTLY

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, external-hard-drive, sleep

External Hard Drive Going to Sleep CONSTANTLY:

I've been a tech 30 years, I've NEVER seen this before. This is not a question I have ever encountered. Toshiba Canvio (Nightmare) external 3tb drive with various videos. Drive falls asleep after 30 seconds of no use or interaction. Drive falls asleep even when Explorer is open on the drive. Drive falls asleep right in the middle of a video playing! WHAT???

Yup. While you're watching a video. MP4, AVI, MPG, etc... Doesn't matter what format, it goes to sleep and whatever app, Media Player, VLC, etc... crashes.

USB power saver in Windows disabled. No information available on this subject, (Except people screaming about what a piece of junk these drives are)

My Question: Is this sleeping thing the external case or the drive itself that's inside?

Comment: Check (and adjust if needed) APM using a tool like Victoria for Windows.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not entirely uncommon... it could be either the enclosure or the disk firmware itself - if you have a Linux system around, then `hdparm` will likely permit you to resolve the issue, if not, then you'll need to look for a Windows alternative.

Comment: Does it automatically resume after it wakes up?  The reason I ask is because these symptoms sound like symptoms I have experience with a hard drive with a failing motor.  I had to unplug, and plug it in again to reboot it.  Eventually that failed to work and the motor and drive were just dead.

Comment: UPDATE - November 2023: Shucked the drive and the Toshiba hard drive by itself does the same thing, (So it was not the enclosure). I've been an avid Western Digital user since 1996. Got this drive at a yard sale. I will not likely ever buy any Toshiba hard drive again.

P.S. Tried everything mentioned in the comments ~ No-Go. Thank you all who contributed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I've seen that issue, particularly with certain brands. The issue of sleeping during *video* playback is caused by the playback app *buffering* the file, i.e., reading ahead on the disk to prevent dropouts. If it buffers 30 seconds or more, the disk sleeps because no data was requested.

There are a few ways to remedy this.

- Reduce the buffer length. This is easily [done in VLC](https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-change-the-buffer-on-vlc) or one could [try decreasing the EVR buffer in MPC-HC](https://linustechtips.com/topic/906337-how-to-increase-mpc-hc-cache-size/).
- Use a tool such as free [KeepAliveHD](https://github.com/stsrki/KeepAliveHD), which simply writes, and overwrites, a few bytes to the external HDD every so often. Ten or twenty second intervals should work for that Canvio drive.

While it might be tempting to leave *KeepAliveHD* running all the time, some external HDD's are not designed for extended use, and could have a shorter operational life.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue and managed to fix it. What I did.

1. In computer management set the USB Controllers to not allow drives to sleep. This did not do anything.
2. Updated the Power management plan to set turn-off disks to Never.

[image: Never]

The Power Management did the trick.

Answer (score -1):

Your case is most likely another issue of too aggressive power saving settings caused be firmware settings of your drive.

In similar cases this behaviour caused the SMART parameter `load cycle count` to increase heavily which contributed to premature use of the drive.

Please note that we all have to accept disadvantages to save the planet, the climate and whatever else comes to your mind.